# Laravel ajax 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Upon form submission I run this ajax:

```
$gradeID=$('#GradeID').val();
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "grades/ajaxprice",
    data: { gradeID: $gradeID}
})
.done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

In my controller I have this:

```
public function getgradeprice()
{
    // $gradeID = Input::get('gradeID');
    // dd($gradeID);
}
```

Here is the route:

```
Route::get('grades/ajaxprice', 'GradesController@ajaxGradePrice');
```

But then I am getting this error:

> 405 Method Not Allowed.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Your route is declared as `GET`, but you're sending `POST` data to it.

Comment: I have change  Route::post('grades/ajaxprice', 'GradesController@ajaxGradePrice'); but get this 500 Internal Server Error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the name of the method could be wrong:

You have:
Route::post('grades/ajaxprice', 'GradesController@ajaxGradePrice');

It must be:
Route::post('grades/ajaxprice', 'GradesController@getgradeprice');

Comment: @I am using this name getgradeprice for another other function?

Comment: I have change this public function ajaxGradePrice()